# Unexpected Rounding Error

Tags: vba, excel

can someone please explain the following to me?

```
Sub TestCalc()
    Dim Z As Double
    Dim Y As Double
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim W As Double
    Dim V As Double
    X = 44 / 14                         ' returns 3
    Z = (0.14 * 14)                     ' returns 1.96
    Y = ((44 / 14) - (44 \ 14)) * 14    ' returns 2 SHOULD RETURN 1.96
    W = (44 / 14) - X                   ' returns 0.142857142857143
    V = W * 14                          ' returns 2 SHOULD RETURN 1.96
End Sub
```

1.96 is the value that I would expect to get from the code.  However, I only get this value when I use hard coded values.  If I work with variables it rounds it up and returns the value 2 (Y or V).  I'm need to understand why, as 1.96 is that value that I expect to be returned.  I need to ensure that it performs this calculation correctly to ensure that my math formula functions properly in my main procedure

Comment: Where do you expect  `1.96`? `V?`. Please be more specific.

Comment: @UGP I would expect the final value of either of the variables Y or V to return 1.96 instead of the value 2 that they return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectations are incorrect.

0.14 * 14 = 1.96; however, W is 0.142857142857143 - that value * 14 = 2.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that there are some unseen conditions determining if the numbers you are entering are being calculated as integers or doubles. What happens when you type out Y as 
`Y = ((44.0 / 14.0) - (44.0 \ 14.0)) * 14.0` 
or however you can specify doubles in Visual Basic.

Also the bottom of this article mentions a mode that warns you when unsafe conversions take place which might help track it down.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/arithmetic-operators

Comment: I have my variables explicitly defined as double.  I've also tried setting them to variant and it makes no difference.